# ООП, правильно ли я думаю по поводу решения?

Tags: ооп

Задание: Игровая комната. Подготовить игровую комнату для детей разных возрастных групп. Игрушек должно быть фиксированное количество в пределах выделенной суммы денег. Должны встречаться игрушки родственных групп, н-р: маленькие, средние и большие машины, куклы, мячи, кубики.

Нужно максимально задействовать ООП, я думаю создать абстрактный класс "игровая комната", от него наследовать классы, например, "младшая группа" и т.п., затем в этих комнатах создать переменную-коллекцию, куда буду помещать игрушки, и константу "бюджет", игрушки в свою очередь будут в себе содержать поле цена. Можете подсказать как можно улучшить все это, усовершенствовать?

Comment: Мне кажется, нужно сделать абстрактный класс(интерфейс) игрушка и от него наследовать все остальные игрушки в целочисленном поле содержать ее бюджет. А класс игровая комната пусть содержит массив указателей на оьщего предка игрушек. Вот вам и полиморфизм, и наследование, и агрегация, и инкапсуляция, и абстрактность.

Comment: И еще потом в этот массив брать игрушки из разных групп ив ычитать их бюджет из оьщего числа бюджета. Как общий выделенный бюджет закончится, игрушки в комнату будут набраны

Comment: Ну другое дело же :) Всё правильно, только еще неплохо бы в игрушках предусмотреть иерархию классов (задание прямо намекает на это). Например `class Машинка extends Игрушка { @override public double getPrice() {...} @override public boolean можетБибикать() {}  ... }